# Search suggestion throwing error

Tags: java, android, search

I am working on local search suggestion in my app. Have create search interface using Search Widget that is interacting well with Searchable Activity.

The problem starts when I modify code to display suggestions. Content Provide child class is created as:

```
public class SearchSuggester extends ContentProvider {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreate() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
        if(selectionArgs!=null && selectionArgs.length>0 && selectionArgs[0]!=null)
        {
            // do Something to return cursor
            return new SQLiteIntegrator(getContext()).getSearchMatch(selectionArgs[0]);
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getType(Uri uri) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Uri insert(Uri uri, ContentValues values) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int delete(Uri uri, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int update(Uri uri, ContentValues values, String selection, String[] selectionArgs) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

SQLiteIntegrator is a class that interacts with the database.

```
public class SQLiteIntegrator extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    Context mContext;
    public SQLiteIntegrator(Context applicationContext)
    {
        super(applicationContext, "SuggestionDB.db", null, 2);
        this.mContext=applicationContext;
    }
    public Cursor getSearchMatch(String catName)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase database=getReadableDatabase();
        String pluralSearch="UPPER(cat_name) like '% "+catName.toUpperCase()+"s %' OR UPPER(cat_name) like '"+catName.toUpperCase()+"s %' OR UPPER(cat_name) like '% "+catName.toUpperCase()+"s' OR UPPER(cat_name)='"+catName.toUpperCase()+"s'";
        String searchQuery="Select * from CatSuggestion where UPPER(cat_name) like '% "+catName.toUpperCase()+" %' OR UPPER(cat_name) like '"+catName.toUpperCase()+" %' OR UPPER(cat_name) like '% "+catName.toUpperCase()+"' OR UPPER(cat_name)='"+catName.toUpperCase()+"' OR "+pluralSearch;
        return database.rawQuery(searchQuery,null);
    }
```

The program is throwing an error:

```
 E/SuggestionsAdapter﹕ error changing cursor and caching columns
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column '_id' does not exist
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(AbstractCursor.java:303)
            at android.database.CursorWrapper.getColumnIndexOrThrow(CursorWrapper.java:78)
            at android.widget.CursorAdapter.swapCursor(CursorAdapter.java:342)
            at android.widget.CursorAdapter.changeCursor(CursorAdapter.java:313)
            at android.widget.SuggestionsAdapter.changeCursor(SuggestionsAdapter.java:264)
            at android.widget.CursorFilter.publishResults(CursorFilter.java:67)
            at android.widget.Filter$ResultsHandler.handleMessage(Filter.java:282)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

I am using database with table CatSuggestion having three fields cat_id,cat_parentid,cat_name .
I haven't used SQLQueryBuilder setProjection though as I don't know how to for existing table.

Please help.

Comment: read http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html, section `"Class Overview"`

Comment: what do you mean: "no help" ?

Comment: I cant figure out how to use SQLQueryBuilder

Comment: what does your `database.rawQuery()` return? did you try to dump it?